# How to install and use GStreamer on latest Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, gstreamer

I have downloaded the latest version of Raspbian today, in the hope of being able to download and use GStreamer.

I need to use GStreamer to stream video across to another computer with minimal delay, currently I am achieving a delay of 2 seconds via VLC player. I need to have minimal if not any delay for the project (eyes for controlling a Lynxmotion Tri-Track robot running with a BotBoarduino).

Using [this tutorial](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-camera/streaming-video-using-gstreamer)  I have reached the step of adding `deb http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates/ . main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`and then `sudo apt-get update` however the following error occurs:

> GPG error: http://vontaene.de. Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

This error is preventing me from being able to install GStreamer.

Answer (score 27):

Just to make sure that nobody looses two hours trying to fix this. 
You do not need to change anything in the `sources.list` anymore.

Install GStreamer with:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the debian-keyring.  Then replace the key 1F41B907 in both placed below with the key that shows up after the "NO PUBLIC KEY" from the end of the update list.  I'm still getting a package error but I think it is just an error in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 1F41B907
gpg --armor --export 1F41B907 | sudo apt-key add -
```