# GStreamer installation on Raspberry Pi for video streaming

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to install GStreamer.

I have added the following line `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates/ .main
```

Calling the `apt-get update` command generates the following error:

> E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
>
> E: The list of sources could not be read."

I tried several ways but nothing seems to work.

Comment: That was it the space between the dot and main Thank you very much

Comment: Now I am stuck with the following error  " The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-omx-dbg : Depends: gstreamer1.0-omx (= 1.0.0.1-0+rpi18rpi1g) but 1.2.0-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. "    tried different command but it does not work. any suggestions people?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Start with fresh Raspbian and do not alter `/etc/apt/sources.list` to install GStreamer. Trying to fix APT repository is possible, but usually time-consuming task.

You can install GStreamer from the official repositories (as suggested in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/46986/34558)):

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools
```

---

Regarding your question: you need to add space between `.` and `main`.

`man sources.list` shows the following structure for the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb [ options ] uri suite [component1] [component2] [...]
```

APT tries constructs an exact URL to the packages using:

```
http://<uri>/dists/<suite>/<component1>/<component2>
```

In case of GStreamer which is served from `http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates/dists/main/`, the correct setting for `sources.list` is:

```
deb http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates/ . main
```

It translates to http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates/dists/./main/ - a reachable addres.

After setting the repository, you'd need to configure the keys. Anyway, currently setting this is unnecessary, see the top of the answer.